# how to display extension .aspx in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

in my web page, aspx extension will display at the time of loading and get removed after loading completes.
I need the extension to be fixed and displayed forever.
how can I fix this?

Comment: check there is any code in your web.config for the hiding the extensions..or also where are you hosted in thar server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aspx extension is not displaying because of the default code generated by asp.net in App_Start\RouteConfig.cs

```
 public static class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
            settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
            routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
        }
    }
```

If you comment out the above codes in RegisterRoutes method, friendly URL option will be removed and URL will be showing as such. In this case aspx.